# how to use Architecture Components ViewModel inside RecyclerView Adapter?

Tags: java, android, android-architecture-components

I have multiple ViewHolders that work as separated views inside a vertical RecyclerView. I'm practicing with the new Architecture Components ViewModel.

Inside my ViewModel I have a couple of MutableLiveData lists that i want to observe, but how can I call

```
ViewModelProviders.of((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).get(FilterViewModel.class)
```

and

```
mFilterViewModel.getCountries().observe(this, new Observer<ArrayList<TagModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable ArrayList<TagModel> tagModels) {

            }
        });
```

without leaking the activity or save the activity inside the adapter?

my ViewModel

```
public class FilterViewModel extends ViewModel {

private final MutableLiveData<ArrayList<TagModel>> mCountries;
private final MutableLiveData<ArrayList<TagModel>> mSelectedCountryProvinceList;
private final MutableLiveData<ArrayList<TagModel>> mDistanceList;

public FilterViewModel(){

    mCountries = new MutableLiveData<>();
    mSelectedCountryProvinceList = new MutableLiveData<>();
    mDistanceList = new MutableLiveData<>();

    TagStore.getInstance().subscribe(new StoreObserver<TagSearchList>() {
        @Override
        public void update(TagSearchList object) {
            mCountries.setValue(object.getCountries());
        }

        @Override
        public void update(int id, TagSearchList object) {
            if (id == 5){
                TagStore.getInstance().unSubcribe(this);
                update(object);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void error(String error) {

        }
    }).get(5,"parent");

    TagStore.getInstance().subscribe(new StoreObserver<TagSearchList>() {
        @Override
        public void update(TagSearchList object) {
            mSelectedCountryProvinceList.setValue(object.toList());
        }

        @Override
        public void update(int id, TagSearchList object) {
            if (id == 6){
                TagStore.getInstance().unSubcribe(this);
                update(object);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void error(String error) {

        }
    }).get(6,"parent");

    TagStore.getInstance().subscribe(new StoreObserver<TagSearchList>() {
        @Override
        public void update(TagSearchList object) {
            mDistanceList.setValue(object.toList());
        }

        @Override
        public void update(int id, TagSearchList object) {
            if (id == 51){
                TagStore.getInstance().unSubcribe(this);
                update(object);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void error(String error) {

        }
    }).get(51,"parent");

}

public void selectCountry(final TagModel country){
    TagStore.getInstance().subscribe(new StoreObserver<TagSearchList>() {
        @Override
        public void update(TagSearchList object) {
            mSelectedCountryProvinceList.setValue(object.toList());
        }

        @Override
        public void update(int id, TagSearchList object) {
            if (id == country.getId()){
                TagStore.getInstance().unSubcribe(this);
                update(object);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void error(String error) {

        }
    }).get(country.getId(),"parent");
}

public LiveData<ArrayList<TagModel>> getCountries(){
    return mCountries;
}

public LiveData<ArrayList<TagModel>> getDistances(){
    return mDistanceList;
}

public LiveData<ArrayList<TagModel>> getProvinces(){
    return mSelectedCountryProvinceList;
}
```

Comment: Hi. Why don't you want to use Android Data Binding instead?

Comment: Hi @JuliaKo, it isn't my intention to refactor my app to MVVM. At the moment i use MVP. i want to use the ViewModel class with the MVP framework to resolve the lifecycle problems, reloading data  and unnecessary Observables.

Comment: I think that what you need is to implement the binding adapter, and the google team are going to make data binding lifecycle aware but for that to happens, lifecycle needs to hit 1.0 stable api. You can take a look at opened issue here: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/issues/34

Comment: Try with this https://android.jlelse.eu/android-architecture-components-room-livedata-and-viewmodel-fca5da39e26b

Answer (score 22):

I am using Room Persistence library. Below is my code for recyclerview adapter using MVVM.

You can see CartViewModel and I have initialized it into the constructor. The constructor gets the context from the activity, and I have cast it into FragmentActivity.

```
private CartViewModel cartViewModel;

public CartListAdapter(Context context, List<CartModel> cartModels) {
        this.context = context;
        this.cartModels = cartModels;

        cartViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of((FragmentActivity) context).get(CartViewModel.class);
    }
```

Here is my full adapter class. I hope it will help.

```
public class CartListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CartListAdapter.CartListViewHolder> {

private static final String TAG = "CartListAdapter";

private Context context;
private List<CartModel> cartModels;

private Double totalQuantity = 0.0;

private CartViewModel cartViewModel;

public CartListAdapter(Context context, List<CartModel> cartModels) {
    this.context = context;
    this.cartModels = cartModels;

    cartViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of((FragmentActivity) context).get(CartViewModel.class);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public CartListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new CartListViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_all_cart_item,parent,false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CartListViewHolder holder, int position) {

    CartModel cartModel = cartModels.get(position);

    Glide.with(context)
            .load(cartModel.getPPICLocate())
            .into(holder.cartItemImage);

    holder.tvCartProductName.setText(cartModel.getProductName());
    holder.tvCartProductCategory.setText(cartModel.getPCategorySubID());
    holder.tvCartProductPrice.setText(cartModel.getPPriceSales());
    holder.etCartProductQuantity.setText(cartModel.getPQuantity());

    holder.btnCartPQtIncrease.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            totalQuantity = Double.valueOf(holder.etCartProductQuantity.getText().toString());
            totalQuantity = totalQuantity+1;
            cartModel.setPQuantity(totalQuantity.toString());
            updateCart(cartModel);
        }
    });

    holder.btnCartPQtDecrease.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            totalQuantity = Double.valueOf(holder.etCartProductQuantity.getText().toString());
            totalQuantity = totalQuantity-1;
            cartModel.setPQuantity(totalQuantity.toString());
            updateCart(cartModel);


        }
    });
}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return cartModels.size();
}

public class CartListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private ImageView cartItemImage;
    private TextView tvCartProductName,tvCartProductCategory,tvCartProductPrice,
            etCartProductQuantity,tvCartProductPrevPrice;
    private ImageButton btnCartPQtIncrease,btnCartPQtDecrease;

    public CartListViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        cartItemImage= itemView.findViewById(R.id.cartItemImage);
        tvCartProductName= itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCartProductName);
        tvCartProductCategory= itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCartProductCategory);
        tvCartProductPrice= itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCartProductPrice);
        etCartProductQuantity= itemView.findViewById(R.id.etCartProductQuantity);
        tvCartProductPrevPrice= itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCartProductPrevPrice);
        btnCartPQtIncrease= itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnCartPQtIncrease);
        btnCartPQtDecrease= itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnCartPQtDecrease);

    }
}

public void addItems(List<CartModel> cartModels) {
    this.cartModels = cartModels;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private void updateCart(CartModel cartModel){
    String tqt = String.valueOf(cartModel.getPQuantity());
    Log.d(TAG, "updateQuantity: "+tqt);
    /*cartRepository.updateCartRepo(cartModel);*/
    cartViewModel.updateCartItemVM(cartModel);

}

}
```

Comment: Why can't we pass the `ViewModel` to `Adapter` directly from the `Activity` along with the `Context`?

Comment: I had the same question @iCantC. Also I do wonder whether either one is a recommended design choice

Comment: Can you please give an example(Code) how am i gonna pass ViewModel to Adapter directly... how am i suppose to do that... Thanks...

Comment: so, where does we add the observe?

Comment: Not a recommended way to do this stuff. It makes code tightly coupled. You should instead use interfaces to implement this stuff inside Fragment or Activity only

Comment: Alternatively, you can just put a setter in your adapter.   I just add a setViewModel(MyViewModel viewmodel)  This gives you some more flexibility because you could swap out (subclassed) viewmodels and reuse the adapter.

Answer (score 2):

You could create an `OnClickListener` interface instead, then implement the `onClick` method (defined in your interface) in your fragment or activity where you have access to your view model.

Comment: This is a common (old) pattern for doing adapter callbacks.  I think it ends up making your calling code sloppy.    However, with viewmodels (and their following of a lifecycle), it's easy to do more than just have a callback- you can also access additional data stored in the viewmodel.

Answer (score -5):

My solution to this issue is;

- create a new variable(ViewModel) for the layout (fragment or activity layout)
- in your activity or fragment get the instance of your viewModel with `ViewModelProviders`
- hold the data which fills your recyclerView in MutableLiveData and observe it and fill the adapter of recyclerView with the value you observed

here you mut be careful not to create adapter instance in observe method.
if you create it in observe method, it will make leaks

Comment: Could you explain why creating an adapter in observe method causes leak?

Comment: @atjua the lambda inside the observe block is called multiple times (when a new value is posted to the LiveData object being observed), so creating a new adapter here may result in having multiple adapters in memory