# How do I change the viewmodel observable data in android?

Tags: android, observable, reactive-programming, android-lifecycle

I created a gridView that has an ArrayAdapter, the gridView contains only photos, I am fetching the image url in an Array and I am observing the array through my activity. Here is my viewmodel

```
class ProfileViewModel constructor(): ViewModel() {
    var first_name: String? = null
    var last_name: String? = null
    var dob: String? = null
    var address: String? = null
    var organization: String? = null
    var hobby: String? = null
    var bio: String? = null
    var imagePath: String = ""

    private val imageList : MutableLiveData<ArrayList<ProfileViewModel>> = MutableLiveData()

    constructor(photo : Photo) : this() {
        this.imagePath = photo.imageUrl
    }

    fun getImageUrl() : String {
        return imagePath
    }

    companion object {
        @BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
        @JvmStatic
        fun loadImage(imageView: ImageView, imageUrl: String) {
            Glide.with(imageView.context)
                .load(imageUrl)
                .apply(RequestOptions.centerCropTransform())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_add_icon)
                .into(imageView)
        }
    }

    val profileViewModels : MutableLiveData<ArrayList<ProfileViewModel>>
        get() {
            val profileViewModels = ArrayList<ProfileViewModel>()

            val photo1 = Photo("")
            val profileVM = ProfileViewModel(photo1)
            repeat(6) {
                profileViewModels.add(profileVM)
            }

            imageList.value = profileViewModels
            return imageList
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my activity where I am observing the data

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val binding: ActivityProfileBinding =
            DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_profile)

        val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(ProfileViewModel::class.java)

        viewModel.profileViewModels.observe(this,
            Observer<ArrayList<ProfileViewModel>> { image_paths ->
                Log.d("added", "$image_paths")
                val imageAdapter = ImageAdapter(this@Profile, R.layout.image_card, image_paths!!)
                gridView.adapter = imageAdapter
            })
}
```

I am getting images in the gridView but I want to update the observable value on gridView Item click in the clicked position. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

First, you can create a function in viewmodel, that you want to do when clicked. for example:

```
private fun doSomethingWhenClicked(listPosition: Int){
    val clickedImage = profileViewModels[position]

    //do something here for clicked image
    //..
}
```

Then, initialize the viewmodel in adapter like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52961599/12426952). So you can update your `profileViewModels` in `onClickListener` inside the `ImageAdapter`

```
viewmodel.doSomethingWhenClicked(position)
```

Hope this answer you!